# PyPika how to select star minus a column

Tags: pypika

I'm trying to use PyPika to build a select statement. Both tables have an `id` column, and I'm trying to select all columns from both tables except the `id` column from the first table.

This is the query I want to end up with, which runs properly in BigQuery:

`SELECT t.* EXCEPT(id), s.* from t join s on t.id = s.id`

I haven't been able to figure out how to get the `EXCEPT` into the select clause.

I've tried the following syntax, but the `except_of()` isn't allowed in this context:

```
t = Table("t")
s = Table("s")
query = Query.from_(t).join(s).on(t.id == s.id).select(t.star.except_of("id")).select(s.star)
```

I also tried a custom function, but that puts an invalid comma in the resulting query. This is what I tried:

```
except_select = CustomFunction("EXCEPT", ["column_to_exclude"])
query = Query.from_(t).join(s).on(t.id == s.id).select(t.star).except_select("id")).select(s.star)
```

which incorrectly generates

`SELECT t.*, EXCEPT(id), s.* from t join s on t.id = s.id`

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

Comment: can you just pass a string so instead of `select(t.star)` `select("t.* EXCEPT(id)")`

Comment: @chiliNUT, that works, thank you! I ended up using `select("* EXCEPT(id)")` .